# Emulator fails to Launch

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, android-emulator, crash-reports, haxm

I was using the emulator perfectly fine yesterday, but today I cannot open the emulator. I have read up on the android documentation and on other issues people have run into and I cannot find a solution. I have attempted to force the emulator to run through the terminal using both -gpu host and -gpu swiftshader_indirect and I was not successful. I have updated all SDK Platforms and SDK Tools with no success. I have deleted the emulator and installed a different emulator through the AVD manager to be certain the download was current.  Here are also some of the trouble shooting commands I have tried with the error messages. I am not sure what to do now. If anyone has any advice, I would greatly appreciate it!

Here is what the Terminal shows:

emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
emulator: WARNING: load_config.cpp:52: Could not parse verified boot config:
emulator: WARNING: load_config.cpp:54:   1:1: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\iante.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disa
bled.
Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.
2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).
3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" t
   o "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/i
ssues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.

crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.
2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).
3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" t
   o "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/i
ssues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.

And this is what the event log reports:

1:30 PM Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!

1:30 PM Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

1:30 PM Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

1:30 PM Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

1:30 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: load_config.cpp:52: Could not parse verified boot config:

1:30 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: load_config.cpp:54:   1:1: Invalid control characters encountered in text.

1:30 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\iante.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

1:30 PM Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

1:30 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1:30 PM Emulator: crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1:30 PM Emulator:

1:30 PM Emulator: 1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

1:30 PM Emulator:

1:30 PM Emulator: 2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

1:30 PM Emulator:

1:30 PM Emulator: 3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

1:30 PM Emulator:

1:30 PM Emulator: Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.

1:30 PM Emulator:

1:30 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

EDIT:

When I restarted my computer, I saw there was an update available for Android Studio, so I updated it accordingly. When I ran the main activity as I have done so previously with my preferred AVD selected the emulator failed to start. Then I attempted to run it through the terminal with both -gpu host and -gpu swiftshader_indirect commands and it still did not work.

SOLUTION TO MY ISSUE:
1. Restart computer.
2. Open Android Studio and run the emulator through the terminal using emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -gpu host.
3. Now run the main activity.

It is beyond me why all of a sudden now this is the work around to run on the emulator when I have previously simply clicked run main activity with my preferred AVD and it would run without problems.

I hope this helps if anyone runs into this issue. I do not think this a complete solution, but I can live with this for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

this from GUI
Go to **Extended Controls** > **Settings** > **Advanced** tab and change `"OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)"` to `"Swiftshader"`.

[image]
[solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbjxh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it this way:

Step 1: `C:\Users\Prashant Kumar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` delete all file

Step 2:Update SDK manager in SDK platform and SDK tools

Step 3: Again we will install emulator with updated package then issue it won't come. now I am able run emulator using cmd .